# Are my SMS messages being intercepted? Or is this some kind of issue with the app itself?

Tags: mobile, phone, smartphone, sms, instant-messaging

When getting verification codes, I've been getting weird messages, such as:

> YoUR siGnaL veRiFICATioN c(O(D(E(: ***-***
>
> YOUR SIgNal VERiFICAtION c)O)D)E): ***-***
>
> yoUR siGnaL veRificATiON c.o.D.e.: ***-***
>
> g-****** iS yOuR g)O)o)g)L)e VeRIficaTiON coDe.
>
> g-****** Is yoUr G)o)O)G)l)e veRificaTion cOde.

What could be the causes of this?

Comment: Are these valid verification codes? I mean, when you enter these into Google and Signal, do they get accepted? Also, which mobile OS and which version are you using?

Comment: Signal is supposed to detect the SMS but it doesn't and I can't input the code manually. I'm using Android 7.1.1

Comment: Is your device rooted? Or did you flash any ROMs manually?

Comment: It has a custom ROM since there's no official Nougat for it, but it's irrelevant since I still get those messages after putting my SIM card in another phone.